# ROS operating system services, how?

Tags: ros, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm researching how ROS is implementing operating services like: including hardware abstraction, low-level device control, implementation of commonly-used functionality,message-passing between processes and package management. Every where I read something about ROS this is stated in the intro but not explained clearly.

Does anyone now how they are implemented or a good source where I can find more information about this? :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237375/ros-operating-system-services,-how-?/) by [pieter](https://answers.ros.org/users/27208/pieter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Walking through the beginner tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) is a good start for any further research. In my opinion, it will be enough for you to start working on low-level controlling after understanding the architecture of ROS (included in beginner tutorials).

For example , doing serial communication between a Linux machine and your device:

1. A simple solution is [building a publisher and a subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).
2. You will need a serial communication library to do the communication jobs, for example the [serial package from William Woodall](http://wiki.ros.org/serial).
3. You'd like to know how to install a package, then maybe [learning about Git](https://git-scm.com/documentation) is good (going through chapter 1 to 3 will be enough for a quick start). And you'll find directly cloning the package from GitHub makes it a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) (don't bother it now, mark it until you come across such problem later).
4. You might want to develop your own library, like a C++ class. Then it is good to know where to put your header file and source files. A lot of related questions are asked, [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/201977/include-header-file-from-another-package-indigo/) is an example.
5. However you still need to manually link the library with the executable target, by working on the CMakeList.txt file ([here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) and [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_libraries.html)) and the [package.xml](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/catkin_library_dependencies.html) file.
6. Based on the above, search more on the Internet.

Wish this help you.

---

Originally posted by [Neur0n](https://answers.ros.org/users/27159/neur0n/) with karma: 56 on 2016-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1